# Hits Cap on multiple Spells

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr4

I have a mystical adept with a magic attribute of 6 (4 adept/2 mage) and spellcasting at 5. So when i cast a spell, it has to be on F1/2 (F3/4) and has a pool of 7 dice. My magic attribute caps the (net?) hits to 2.
Correct me if i'm wrong.

The question:
If i cast 2 spells at once, i split my dice but do i have to split my hit cap as well? Otherwise, casting 2 spells should be my way to go, right?

Comment: Hi Kaminari, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have found the answer by myself...
The hits cap isn't your Magic atrribute but the force of the spell, therefore each spell has it's own cap.

And it caps the hits (not net hits).